# Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled ReactJs error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to handle changes in my form. I have title, description, and category.

The first input(title) -> Unable to type in the field.

The second input(description) -> Able to type in field but result is undefined.

The 3rd input(category DDL) -> Unable to change selected category, but default selected is being outputted in my alret as 'drink';

Problem:

> AddDeal is changing a controlled input of type text to be
>   uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
>   uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I have viewed the react document here on controlled components but finding it hard to understand as I'm new to it.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Here is my code for `AddDeal.js`

```
export default class AddDeal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set the state
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      description: '',
      category: 'technology'
    };

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('Title is: ' + this.state.title + 'Description is: ' + this.state.description + 'Category is: ' + this.state.category);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      title: e.target.title,
      description: e.target.description,
      category: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add Deal</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <label><input value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="title"/></label>
        <label><input value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="description" /></label>
        <select value={this.state.category} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="food">Food</option>
            <option value="drink">Drink</option>
            <option value="books">Books</option>
          </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why is this so hard to grab inputs? Should I be using props instead of state? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I never saw this post, but after reading through it, using state for handling inputs is becoming alot clearer. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is in `onChange function`, you are using common onChange function so instead of updating all with same value update the specific state value.

Use this function:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    }); 
}
```

Use **name property to update the specific state**, and you need to define the `name='category'` with select field.

Check the working example:

```js
class AddDeal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Set the state
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      description: '',
      category: 'technology'
    };

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('Title is: ' + this.state.title + 'Description is: ' + this.state.description + 'Category is: ' + this.state.category);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add Deal</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <label><input value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="title"/></label>
        <label><input value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="description" /></label>
        <select name='category' value={this.state.category} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="food">Food</option>
            <option value="drink">Drink</option>
            <option value="books">Books</option>
          </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddDeal/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: @MaynakShukla works perfect, thank you! I still don't get why I can't just handleChange by targeting all the events separately in the form but I'm learning as I go.

Comment: Could I also change the value on the inputs to {this.state.value} on all 3 and get the results that way aswell?

Comment: didn't get the first ques. you can use either separate onChange handlers for each field, but here you are using a common change so at a time that function will get called by any one of the field so you need to update only that state variable which is associated to that field. **2nd ques:** no because this.state.value does't exist, you have separate state variable for  different fields. let me know if you need any other help :)

Answer (score 0):

change your function to

```
 handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    }); 
}
```