# Is there a neater way to connect an input field to a state property in React than onChange?

Tags: reactjs

So look at this code below for our example, a simple 2-way data-binding on an input field connecting the field to a property `inputValue`.

But say you have a more complex page with 30 or more inputs. Are you supposed to write 30+ `onChange` handlers in the class, all with different names corresponding to the inputs like `onNameChange`, `onEmailChange`, `onPhoneChange`, and so on? Is there no neater, more implicit way to bind inputs than what I have below here?

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    inputValue: ''
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type='text'
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  },
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }
});
```

**Edit:** I suppose I could do this and avoid writing handlers on the class:

```
<input onChange={ e => this.setState({firstName: e.target.value}) } />
```

Is that kosher?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43695213/5185595

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React docs has your solution:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

```
    class NameForm extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

   handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;    
    this.setState({
      [target.name]: target.value
    });
  }

      handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Name:
              <input name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <label>
              Email:
              <input name="email" type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
                  <label>
              Pet:
              <input name="country" type="text" value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: it will fail, 1.you are storing all the value in same state variable, if you change any one all the values will get changed. 2. you are using e.target.name, but didn't define any name with input fields.

Comment: @MayankShukla thanks.. i did it quickly and forgot some important stuff..

Comment: you need to change this also: `value={this.state.value}` instead of that it should be `value={this.state.name}` `value={this.state.email}` `value={this.state.country}` otherwise input fields will be read-only :)

Comment: you need to change this also: `value={this.state.value}` instead of that it should be `defaultValue` otherwise input fields will be read-only

@MayankShukla idea is right. may be typo

Answer (score 1):

The neater way would be to have a single `onChange` handler and pass on the id to it, and store the value with that id. Your solution will look like

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {

  },
  onChange(e, type) {
     this.setState({[type]: e.target.value})

  },
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type='text'
        value={(this.state.inputValue)? this.state.inputValue: ''}
        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'inputValue')} />
      <input
        type='text'
        value={(this.state.emailValue)? this.state.emailValue: ''}
        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'emailValue')} />
    );
  },
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }
});
```

The value is given with a `ternary operator expression` because initially the state is not defined and hence we will get a `warning that input is trying to change the uncontrolled input to controlled.`

The other way is to have the handler inline like

```
onChange={ e => this.setState({inputValue: e.target.value}) }
```

but say you have 30 inputs you need to define their initial state and let it set its value like above, only difference being the value being assigned to it should be with the expression as shown in the first example

The other way to assign value to the input as @MayankShukla suggessted will be

```
value = {this.state.inputValue || ''}
```

with getInitialState looking like

```
getInitialState() {
    return {}
},
```

Comment: i think, instead of that `(this.state.inputValue)? this.state.inputValue: ''` you can write `this.state.inputValue || ''` and return `{}` inside `getInitialState` :)

Comment: Yeah, @MayankShukla you are right. This way will be simpler. Will edit the post to include your suggesstion